# Glassfish4.0 fails to start in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I cannot get Glassfish to start in eclipse it gets stuck at 69%.
Ive tried everything i have found online like deleting osgi-cache.
I have tried creating a new domain but still fails to start. there is nothing running on the ports (8080,4848). the weird thing is it starts no problem from the asadam command line it just fails to start within eclipse. I am using kepler, I tried downloading luna and adding glassfish to that but still gets stuck on 69%

here is there server log:

```
[2015-03-06T12:50:14.197+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler] [tid: _ThreadID=202 _ThreadName=admin-listener(27)] [timeMillis: 1425646214197] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.10.4 2014-08-08 15:09:00...]]

[2015-03-06T12:50:14.327+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-REST-00001] [javax.enterprise.admin.rest] [tid: _ThreadID=202 _ThreadName=admin-listener(27)] [timeMillis: 1425646214327] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Listening to REST requests at context: /command/domain.]]

[2015-03-06T12:50:14.407+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00092] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=3045 _ThreadName=Thread-27] [timeMillis: 1425646214407] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server shutdown initiated]]

[2015-03-06T12:50:14.407+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00028] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=3045 _ThreadName=Thread-27] [timeMillis: 1425646214407] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@e7135c5 from service registry.]]

[2015-03-06T12:50:14.407+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=3045 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1425646214407] [levelValue: 800] [[
  FileMonitoring shutdown]]

[2015-03-06T12:50:14.417+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00001] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=3045 _ThreadName=Thread-27] [timeMillis: 1425646214417] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JMXStartupService and JMXConnectors have been shut down.]]

[2015-03-06T12:50:14.697+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=3052 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1425646214697] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JdbcRuntimeExtension,  getAllSystemRAResourcesAndPools = [GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource]]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:18.800+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00009] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1425646278690] [timeMillis: 1425646278800] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:18.810+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00010] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1425646278690] [timeMillis: 1425646278810] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:19.541+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.monitor] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1425646278690] [timeMillis: 1425646279541] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Successfully got INSTRUMENTATION: sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl@397421ba]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:19.571+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1425646278700] [timeMillis: 1425646279571] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:19.581+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1425646278690] [timeMillis: 1425646279581] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:19.591+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1425646278690] [timeMillis: 1425646279591] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:19.601+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1425646278690] [timeMillis: 1425646279601] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:19.691+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [SEC-SVCS-00100] [javax.enterprise.security.services] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1425646278690] [timeMillis: 1425646279691] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Authorization Service has successfully initialized.]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:19.961+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1425646278700] [timeMillis: 1425646279961] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 160ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:20.161+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1425646278700] [timeMillis: 1425646280161] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 90ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:20.251+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1425646278700] [timeMillis: 1425646280251] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 30ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:20.341+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1425646278690] [timeMillis: 1425646280341] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 10ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:20.351+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00017] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1425646280351] [levelValue: 800] [[
  GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (17,967ms), startup services(1,671ms), total(19,638ms)]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:20.541+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [NCLS-JMX-00007] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=Thread-12] [timeMillis: 1425646280541] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Cannot start JMX connector JmxConnector config: { name = system, Protocol = rmi_jrmp, Address = 0.0.0.0, Port = 8686, AcceptAll = false, AuthRealmName = admin-realm, SecurityEnabled = true} due to exception java.lang.NullPointerException]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:20.551+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1425646280551] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.ssl.SecureRMIServerSocketFactory.<init>(SecureRMIServerSocketFactory.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.RMIConnectorStarter.<init>(RMIConnectorStarter.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.startConnector(JMXStartupService.java:310)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.run(JMXStartupService.java:350)]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:20.731+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1425646278700] [timeMillis: 1425646280731] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 80ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:20.791+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00027] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1425646280791] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@20dc4786 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@9890172.]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:21.391+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646281391] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:22.531+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646282531] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:22.541+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646282541] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:22.551+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646282551] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:22.591+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646282591] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created virtual server server]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:22.591+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646282591] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created virtual server __asadmin]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:22.611+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1425646282611] [levelValue: 800] [[
  org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.client.ReflectiveClientInvoker
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
CAUSE:  java.lang.NullPointerException
id=237
target=org.glassfish.web.admin.monitor.HttpServiceStatsProvider@56f06065
method=public void org.glassfish.web.admin.monitor.HttpServiceStatsProvider.connectionAcceptedEvent(java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String)
paramNames=[listenerName, connection, address]
probeIndices=[0, 1, 2]
useProbeArgs=true
hasComputedParams=false]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:22.611+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1425646282611] [levelValue: 800] [[
  org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.client.ReflectiveClientInvoker
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
CAUSE:  java.lang.NullPointerException
id=231
target=org.glassfish.web.admin.monitor.HttpServiceStatsProvider@3fa61429
method=public void org.glassfish.web.admin.monitor.HttpServiceStatsProvider.connectionAcceptedEvent(java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String)
paramNames=[listenerName, connection, address]
probeIndices=[0, 1, 2]
useProbeArgs=true
hasComputedParams=false]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:23.013+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-CORE-00306] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646283013] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:23.013+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00201] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646283013] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Virtual server server loaded default web module ]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:23.733+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-SECURITY-05054] [javax.enterprise.system.security.ssl] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646283733] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  The SSL certificate has expired: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 23741889829347261660812437366387754385443431973861114865490414153884050331745811968523116847625570146592736935209718565296053386842135985534863157983128812774162998053673746470782252407673402238146869994438729551246768368782318393878374421033907597162218758024581735139682087126982809511479059100617027892880227587855877479432885604404402435662802390484099065871430585284534529627347717530352189612077130606642676951640071336717026459037542552927905851171460589361570392199748753414855675665635003335769915908187224347232807336022456537328962095005323382940080676931822787496212635993279098588863972868266229522169377
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Aug 14 15:50:00 BST 1998,
               To: Thu Aug 15 00:59:00 BST 2013]
  Issuer: CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    01b6]

Certificate Extensions: 4
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:5
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.2.840.113763.1.2.1.3]
[]  ]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 76 0A 49 21 38 4C 9F DE   F8 C4 49 C7 71 71 91 9D  v.I!8L....I.qq..
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 41 3A D4 18 5B DA B8 DE   21 1C E1 8E 09 E5 F1 68  A:..[...!......h
0010: 34 FF DE 96 F4 07 F5 A7   3C F3 AC 4A B1 9B FA 92  4.......<..J....
0020: FA 9B ED E6 32 21 AA 4A   76 C5 DC 4F 38 E5 DF D5  ....2!.Jv..O8...
0030: 86 E4 D5 C8 76 7D 98 D7   B1 CD 8F 4D B5 91 23 6C  ....v......M..#l
0040: 8B 8A EB EA 7C EF 14 94   C4 C6 F0 1F 4A 2D 32 71  ............J-2q
0050: 63 2B 63 91 26 02 09 B6   80 1D ED E2 CC B8 7F DB  c+c.&...........
0060: 87 63 C8 E1 D0 6C 26 B1   35 1D 40 66 10 1B CD 95  .c...l&.5.@f....
0070: 54 18 33 61 EC 13 4F DA   13 F7 99 AF 3E D0 CF 8E  T.3a..O.....>...
0080: A6 72 A2 B3 C3 05 9A C9   27 7D 92 CC 7E 52 8D B3  .r......'....R..
0090: AB 70 6D 9E 89 9F 4D EB   1A 75 C2 98 AA D5 02 16  .pm...M..u......
00A0: D7 0C 8A BF 25 E4 EB 2D   BC 98 E9 58 38 19 7C B9  ....%..-...X8...
00B0: 37 FE DB E2 99 08 73 06   C7 97 83 6A 7D 10 01 2F  7.....s....j.../
00C0: 32 B9 17 05 4A 65 E6 2F   CE BE 5E 53 A6 82 E9 9A  2...Je./..^S....
00D0: 53 0A 84 74 2D 83 CA C8   94 16 76 5F 94 61 28 F0  S..t-.....v_.a(.
00E0: 85 A7 39 BB D7 8B D9 A8   B2 13 1D 54 09 34 24 7D  ..9........T.4$.
00F0: 20 81 7D 66 7E A2 90 74   5C 10 C6 BD EC AB 1B C2   ..f...t\.......

]]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:23.743+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01001] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646283743] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Java security manager is enabled.]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:23.753+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01010] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646283753] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Entering Security Startup Service.]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:23.753+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01143] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646283753] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:23.803+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01011] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646283803] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Security Service(s) started successfully.]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:24.023+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646284023] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:24.073+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646284073] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:24.073+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646284073] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:29.347+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [jsf.config.listener.version] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646289347] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context '']]

[2015-03-06T12:51:31.016+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646291016] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:32.126+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646292126] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [__admingui] at [/]]]

[2015-03-06T12:51:32.126+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00022] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1425646292126] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application __admingui done in 11,585 ms]]
```

I'm lost for ideas at this stage. Any help would be great
Thanks

Comment: the same issue I'm having with `eclipse luna` using `glassfish 4.0`

Answer (score 0):

This exception can occur when there's a configuration issue in your domain.xml.
You may have re-used the default virtual server's existing Network Listeners / Protocol.

I was able to fix this issue by leaving intact the default virtual server named "server" and it's network listener / protocol and creating new network listeners / protocols and an associated virtual server for my application.

Creating these entries through either the command line or web gui will help prevent syntax issues, but reading through the domain.xml can be uncover bad settings that the web gui may not reveal.